# Is there a simple way to display months in a pivot table as per fiscal year?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have a dataset with dates for the past 4 years.
I have an appointment column (appt date) with format mm/dd/yyyy and customer column (cust ID)

I would like to create pivot tables displaying the number of customers in a fiscal year, which runs April 1-Mar 31. Therefore, I would like the rows to look like, for example:

2022:
Apr
May
Jun
July
Aug
Sep
Oct
Nov
Dec
2023:
Jan
Feb
Mar

Is there a way to either
a) filter in the pivot table to months in a fiscal year
b) a conditional column that could be created in power query to label the appointment date to the corresponding fiscal year

Thank you!

Comment: make the pivot table > add `date` to column field - remove quarter field > add `id` to value field > select 'dont show subtitle' from design tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try either of the following:

**METHOD 1 - Calculated Columns in the Source Table:**

Insert a new column in the data table for "*Fiscal Year*", and use the following formula:

```
=YEAR([@[appt date]])+(MONTH([@[appt date]])>3)
```

Insert another new column in the data table for "*Fiscal Month*", and use the following formula:

```
=TEXT(CHOOSE(MONTH([@[appt date]]),10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),"00")&TEXT([@[appt date]]," - mmm")
```

Then, with your data table selected, go to **Insert > Pivot Table**.

[image: add_to_source_table.png]

**METHOD 2 - Custom Columns in Power Query:**

In Excel, select your data table, then go to **Data > Get & Transform Data > From Table/Range**.

In Power Query Editor, go to **Add Column > Custom Column**, name it "*Fiscal Year*" and use the following column formula:

```
= Date.Year( Date.AddMonths( [appt date], 9) )
```

Again, go to **Add Column > Custom Column**, name it "*Fiscal Month*" and use the following column formula:

```
= Number.ToText( Date.Month( Date.AddMonths( [appt date], - 3 ) ), "00" ) & DateTime.ToText( [appt date], " - MMM" )
```

Then, go to **File > Close & Load To...** and select "*Pivot Table Report*".

[image: add_with_power_query.png]